# Is it possible to use a laptop as an external storage device?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, connection

I want to use my laptop as an external storage device with my PC. Is this possible? Is there a way to keep a backup of a file on my laptop hard drive and is there any software that can keep the backup on the laptop in sync with the PC?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you wish to remove the drive from the laptop and use it externally? If so, there are relativity cheap USB 2.5" HDD enclosures that will work perfectly.

Comment: @Rain           No, I want to use it without removing it, I was thinking a way to use my laptop hard disk space (not entirely!) for the back up files on my personal computer, as I think there should be a way to use your laptop hard drive as a storage device with a sync feature. And yes! I am not thing of buying an external hard drive right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to share your laptop drive to the network:
http://www.ehow.com/how_2019957_shared-drive-network.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW4jor40Pw0

Then you need to map it to the desktop PC:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-map-a-drive-in-windows/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZURjAaSGQRE

Then use a tool to keep them in sync. SyncToy from MS is a decent enough solution:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiNZPzFxoSc

*edit* I should note, that it is not totally necessary to map the laptop drive on the desktop, it just makes it a bit easier to access

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: can you recommend me any video from youtube?

Comment: updated answer with youtube links

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the hard drive directly, you want [an enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=-1&isNodeId=1&Description=2%205%20drive%20enclosure).

If you're looking to do a backup, check out [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com). Free version will do it.

If you're looking to use it as "live" storage on a running other machine, you'll need to create a share and map a drive.

Comment: - I do not want to remove laptop hard drive - so an enclosure is of no use, and I do not want to use online storage.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use it, but for clarity CrashPlan's free application lets you perform backups between your own computers/storage, not the cloud.

Comment: Yup. Free version will not backup "to the cloud". Only to another PC (local or remote). If creating shares and mapping drives is foreign to you, you'll have a better time with a packaged solution I would think. Or it can be a learning experience. :)